# Angularjs and Spring session management

Tags: angularjs, spring, session, spring-security

I'm using angularjs and spring security together.

Everything is fine, but session management problem hasn't been solving.

this is my code => **security.xml**

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/sessionout">
            <concurrency-control expired-url="/login" />
</session-management>
```

angularjs router can't catch a url `/sessinout`. So I don't know how to deal with this. What I have to do, to deal with that url?

And last question!!
At the first, I thought I didn't need that `<session-management>` tag. 
however, without that tag, front didn't recognize that session had gone out.
How to deal with spring security session with angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

A late response, to help other people searching an answer. You have to distinguish url catch by your java controller and others catch by angularjs.

If in your app.js you've got a path route like

```
 .when('/error/expired', {
      templateUrl: 'error/expired',
 })
```

Angularjs will catch the following url with hashbang

http://localhost/app/#/error/expired

If you use the following url, in my case using thymeleaf for templating, I have got some java controller.

http://localhost/app/error/expired

You will reach the java controller with the corresponding url

Of course this solution works if the html5 mode in the locationProvider is not used.

To answer to the question

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/#/sessionout">
```

Would be redirect to angular rooter.